# Replace of unicode codes

Tags: r, string, unicode, character-encoding, unicode-string

How to convert \u0085 code to normal character?

I have list of words that are badly coded, like "zwia\u0085zany", It is any method to convert that string? Result of this conversion sholud be "związany".

I am writing script in R now and I have to deal with many examples of that kind of words. I have tried methods like 
iconv:
iconv("zwia\u0085zany", to="utf-8")
stringi:
stri_trans_general("zwia\u0085zany", "latin-ascii")

Any of above methods dosent work for me. Please help

Comment: If you have already have a unicode string but you are seeing `\uXXXX` sequences in it, then perhaps the problem is the encoding you are using to print it, rather than needing to do a conversion.

Comment: Your problem is that, `\u0085` is unicode for `next line` or `\n`: [see link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/85/index.htm)

Comment: It is interesting to note that [ą](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0105/index.htm) encoded by UTF-8 is 0xC4 0x85. Did the 0xC4 byte somehow get dropped and the 0x85 somehow get erroneously interpreted as the UTF-16 "\u0085"? Can you find and fix the problem upstream?

Comment: @TomBlodget no I can't, I thnik that I should replace all unicode sequences with proper characters.

Comment: Note: If we assume UTF-8 bytes were lost and assume that \u0085 is an erroneous representation for the only byte that remains, there are 2026 codepoints that have 0x85 as one of the bytes in UTF-8. For example, ǅ, х, Ӆ, ಅ, . It seems like you have unrecoverable data loss due to a human error.